Theme Change Not Reflecting in Jetpack Compose App After Switching in ThemeScreen
I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose and trying to implement a dynamic theme change functionality. The theme is set using a custom PlanstyTheme function, and users can select the theme from a ThemeSelectionScreen. The theme selection is supposed to update the app's appearance immediately, but the change doesn't seem to take effect after switching the theme in ThemeScreen.
Here's a snippet of my MainActivity:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    val preferences: AppPreferences by inject()
    setContent {
        val viewmodel: MainScreenModel by inject()
        val isOnBoardingDone by preferences.isOnboardingComplete.collectAsState(initial = false)
        val appTheme by viewmodel.appTheme.collectAsState(initial = AppTheme.SYSTEM)
        val accentColor by viewmodel.accentColor.collectAsState(initial = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)

        Log.i("theme name Main", appTheme.name)
        Log.i("accent theme name Main", "${accentColor.value}")

        PlanstyTheme(appTheme = appTheme, accentColor = accentColor) {
            if (isOnBoardingDone) {
                Navigator(MainContainer)
            } else {
                Navigator(OnboardingScreen)
            }
        }
    }
}

and below is my Theme composable Method
    @Composable
fun PlanstyTheme(
    appTheme: AppTheme,
    accentColor: Color,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val dark = appTheme == AppTheme.DARK || (appTheme == AppTheme.SYSTEM && isSystemInDarkTheme())

    val colorScheme = when {
        dark -> darkScheme.copy(primary = accentColor)
        else -> lightScheme.copy(primary = accentColor)
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        localColorScheme provides colorScheme
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colorScheme = colorScheme,
            content = content
        )
    }

    // Handle system UI colors
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !dark
        }
    }


and i will paste the code from my datastore too
    class AppPreferences(private val context: Context) {

    // to make sure there's only one instance
    companion object {
        private val Context.appPreference: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("preferences")

        //keys
        val ONBOARDING_KEY = booleanPreferencesKey("onboarding")
        val POINTS_KEY = intPreferencesKey("points")

        private val THEME_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("theme")
        private val ACCENT_COLOR_KEY = intPreferencesKey("accent_color")
    }

    // themes and accents
    suspend fun saveTheme(theme: AppTheme) {
        context.appPreference.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[THEME_KEY] = theme.name
        }
        Log.i("datastore theme","$theme")
    }

    fun getTheme() = context.appPreference.data.map { preferences ->

       val theme = preferences[THEME_KEY] ?: AppTheme.SYSTEM.name
        Log.i("get datastore theme","$theme")
        AppTheme.valueOf(theme)

    }

    suspend fun saveAccentColor(color: Color) {
        context.appPreference.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[ACCENT_COLOR_KEY] = color.toArgb()
        }
    }

    fun getAccentColor() = context.appPreference.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[ACCENT_COLOR_KEY]?.let { Color(it) } ?: Color.Gray
    }
}
enum class AppTheme {
    SYSTEM, LIGHT, DARK
}

there are other codes too where i update the theme in my viewmodel to datastore if you need to see that i can edit an provide the code

Note: I use voyager for navigation and screenmodel
and i also notice when i chane themes the status bar change but the whole Ui doesn't


as requested I'll add the code for the MainScreenModel below
class MainScreenModel(private val preferences: AppPreferences) : ScreenModel {

val appTheme = preferences.getTheme()

val accentColor = preferences.getAccentColor()}

when i close and reopen the app, the Theme then changes
if you have any suggestion I'd really appreciate it i've been at this all day

What you are missing is updating the UI when the color scheme changes. You do update the DataStore and that is why when you re-launch the application, the theme changes.

This question is similar to: Jetpack Compose: How to change theme from light to dark mode programmatically onClick. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it's similar, but all the solution in that question didn't help

What you are missing is updating the UI when the color scheme changes where should i do this that i haven't done already?? it's so simple yet so tricky

Please add MainScreenModel code to the question. the interesting part is how you define appTheme and how you update it's value so it'll be updating the composable

i just added the MainScreenViewmodel

Using Material theme I cant even apply a theme to my fragments, only main activity inherit the theme change.

The solution was downgrading the version of the voyager I used, and that solved the theme change problem

This seems to be backed by datastore-preferences?
Therefore OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener cannot be utilized. In Compose, you'd need MutableState or even MutableStateFlow. Also see: State in composables. You're assigning the value with collectAsState(), which probably rather should be mutableStateOf() in order to be mutable, observable and to cause recomposition.
I'm unsure, what appTheme is supposed to be:
val appTheme by viewmodel.appTheme.collectAsState(initial = AppTheme.SYSTEM)

But this probably should be more alike (theme resId are int):
val appTheme: Int by remember { mutableIntStateOf(AppTheme.SYSTEM) }

These initial values would need to be default values in/from DataStore, or provided otherwise:
initial = false
initial = AppTheme.SYSTEM
initial = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer


let me try it and get back to you! Thanks for the response

so i made changes according to what you suggested, i'll paste the code change below

val appTheme = remember { mutableStateOf(AppTheme.SYSTEM) }
val accentColor = remember { mutableStateOf(accentColorInitial) }
LaunchedEffect(
) {
viewmodel.appTheme.collect { theme ->
appTheme.value = theme
}
viewmodel.accentColor.collect { color ->
accentColor.value = color
}
}

at this point feel like i don't know what i'm doing even though I've used theming done this countless times. Also i used voyager for navigation, maybe it might be contributing to the woes.

This article might explain the differences, it's about the initialization already, when desiring to mutate values later - there's several ways with pros and contras: https://skydoves.medium.com/loading-initial-data-in-launchedeffect-vs-viewmodel-f1747c20ce62

i think the problem is with the navigation Library i used “Voyager”, and it happens only when i use a certain component “Tab Navigator”, every other time the theme show but once i add it, the screen just stop recomposing and reacting to theme change
